# c language how to find two hop neighbors in adjacency matrix

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define M 20
#define N 20
int main()
{
    int i, j, x,a,b;
    int G[20][20] = { {0} };
    /*creaate random adjaceney matrix*/
    printf("==================================================\n");
    printf("Welcome to my Graph Processing tool!\n\n");

srand(time(NULL));
for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        if (i == j) {
            G[i][j] = 0;
        }
        else {
            G[i][j] = rand() % 2;
            G[j][i] = G[i][j];
        }
    }
}
/*check whether the whole row equals to 0*/
for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
    if (G[j] == 0) {
        x = rand() % 20 + 1;
        G[x][j] = G[j][x] = 1;
    }
    /*print the matrix G*/
    else
    {

        printf("The adjacency for graph G is\n");
        for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                printf("%d ", G[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}

    /*all one-hop neighbors*/
    printf("\nList of one-hop neighbors:");
    for (i = 0; i < M;i++) {
        printf("\nVertex %d: ", i);
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            if (G[i][j] == 1) {

                printf("%d ",j);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n===================================\n\n");


    /*two-hop neighbors*/
    printf("List of two-hop neighbors:");
    /*for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        printf("\nVertex %d: ", i);
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {

            if (G[i][j] == 1) {                     
                    for (a = 0; a < 20; a++) {
                        if (G[a][j] == 1 && G[a][i] != 1 /*&& G[a][j] == 1 && G[i][a] != 1) {

                            printf("%d ", a);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    printf("\n=================================================\n");*/

    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        printf("\nVertex %d: ", i);
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)/*; for(a=0;a<j;a++)*/ {
            for (a = 0; a < 20; a++) {
                if (G[i][j] == 1 && i != j) {
                    if (G[a][j] == 1 && G[a][i] != 1 && a != i && a != j && i != j) {
                        printf("%d ", a);
                    }

                }
                /*else {
                    printf("NONE");
                }*/
            }
        }

        }

    printf("\n============================================\n");


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

the code at 1st is to generate a 20x20 random adjacency matrix
the matrix is G[i][j]
it is symmetric only have 0 and 1 in matrix 
the main diagonal of the matrix are all 0

then i find one-hop neighbors
the one-hop neighbors part i am sure it is correct

the answer of the 2-hop neighbors part is wrong

my idea is if G[i][j]=1, G[a][j]=1 and G[a][i] !=1,then i and a will be two-hop neighbor

but how to loop a?
how to find two-hop neighbor by using for loops?

i have got the image output here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tz6PI.jpg)

Comment: I don't understand the part with `x = rand() % 20 + 1` where you assign 1 to a random place in the matrix, which may be even in the main diagonal if x == j or out of bounds if j == 19 and x == 20. That apart, your code seems OK. Why do you say it is wrong ? Any example ?

Comment: the matrix which i generate is ok
the wrong part is that finding two-hop neighbor part

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is correct. To avoid too many nested for loops, let's write a function to test whether two nodes are two-hops neighbors:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool distance_is_two (int i, int j)
{
    if ((i == j) || (G[i][j] == 1)) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
        if ((k == i) || (k == j)) {
            continue;
        }

        if ((G[i][k] == 1) && (G[k][j] == 1)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: what if I want to use for loop instead of bool? because haven't learn bool yet